# How to find the MSE and MAPE metrics on test data with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have the following LSTM model.
How I can check the MSE or MAPE metrics on the test data?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
X_train = np.random.randn(100, 5, 1)
Y_train = np.random.randn(100, 1)
X_test = np.random.randn(20, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(Y_train.shape[1]))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=100, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
mape_loss = keras.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error(Y_test, prediction)
mse_loss = keras.metrics.mean_squared_error(Y_test, prediction)
```

[Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/mean_absolute_percentage_error)

Comment: It provides an array.  thanks for providing this lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do so installing [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html).

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(Y_test, prediction)
mse = mean_squared_error(Y_test, prediction)
```

You can [read more about it](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html).